# Can't get values ​entered in ASP.NET MVC Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

First of all my codes:

`ManageClass.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Class' Management";
}

<br />
<h2>Add Class</h2>

<form method="post" asp-controller="AddClassDB" asp-action="">
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    </div> </div>
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Class Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="classNameInput">
  <br/>
  <div class="float-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  </div>
  <br />
  <h2>Manage Class</h2>
</form>
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using StudentWeb.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StudentWeb.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ManageClass()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult AddClassDB(ClassTable _table)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_table);
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

I will take the value of `classNameInput` in `ManageClass.cshtml` and save it to SQL. I will do the saving in the `Controller`, but I have not yet received the value entered by the user.

But after I enter the value in the input and press the `submit` button, I get the following result:

[image]

[image]
(page not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong value for `asp-controller` and `asp-action` for the form. Hence it generates the wrong `action` path for the form.

It should be:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddClassDB">
 ...
</form>
```

By default, all the *action* methods in the controller are **GET** (method). You need to apply `[HttpPost]` attribute so that the `AddClassDB` is recognized as **POST** (method).

```cs
[HttpPost("AddClassDB")]
public ActionResult AddClassDB(ClassTable _table)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_table);
   
    // TO-DO Redirect to view that is existed
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile, you also need to use `name` attribute in the `<input>` element as passing value (mapping to the object property) to the controller.

Comment: I got a different error: https://imgur.com/a/w68Xqc7

Comment: Sorry about that, done update the answer. You need to apply `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: Doubt that there is no `AddClassDB` page, `return View();` in `AddClassDB` will throw an error, you need to specify which page you want to redirect. Example: `return View("Your Page");`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. I will ask one last thing. I'm a new MVC Controller with views, using entity framework. Then the following folders were created: https://imgur.com/a/Xjl4wdO. How can I save the value I get from Input to MS SQL with these? Finally, if you can help me with this, I will be very grateful. After creating the Controller, `ClassTablesController.cs` and `ClassTable` folders were created automatically.

Comment: No problem. Ya, Entity Framework is an ORM to use for performing CRUD (create/insert, retrieve/select, update, delete) operations. In short, first you need to build a data context class depending on Database-First or Code First approach. I think this article [Tutorial: Get started with EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is good to read and refer.

Comment: I looked at the link you gave and tried to do it, but I couldn't do it. If I submit my project on GitHub, can you do it? Can I learn by looking at what you do?